# W3.js html table filter - onkeyup timeout

Tags: javascript, php, filter, html-table, onkeyup

I am new to Javascript and need help with following problem:
Currently I have php page, where I generate html table from .xml file. Its working with this PHP function:

```
 function xmlToHtmlTable($p_oXmlRoot) {  
  $bIsHeaderProceessed = false;  

  $sTHead = '';  
  $sTBody = '';       
  foreach ($p_oXmlRoot as $oNode) {  
       $sTBody .= '<tr class=item>';  
       foreach ($oNode as $sName => $oValue){  
            if (!$bIsHeaderProceessed) {  
                 $sTHead .= "<th>{$sName}</th>";  
            }  
            $sValue = (string)$oValue;  
            $sTBody .= "<td>{$sValue}</td>";                 
       }  
       $bIsHeaderProceessed = true;  
       $sTBody .= '</tr>';  
  }  

  $sHTML = "<table id=demo border=1>  
                 <thead><tr>{$sTHead}</tr></thead>  
                 <tbody>{$sTBody}</tbody>  
            </table>";  
  return $sHTML;
```

The table generated is pretty long and I need filtering option for it. I found simple solution that meets my requirements using w3.js filter table function. I have one input field that does the filtering:

```
<input onkeyup="w3.filterHTML('#demo', '.item', this.value)" placeholder="Filter">
```

Everything is working good but very slow, the table is +2000 lines long and the search is processing every single character typed and refreshing the results. What I need is to execute typed word/number/... after lets say 2 sec.

I have found similar questions here, but I cannot make it work with w3.js (maybe doing something wrong, as I said I am just beginning with JS).

Answer (score 0):

In angularjs there is a concept called  ng-minlength="2".. which means that search will be performed only after search string is 2 characters at least. So I made that in javascript. Instead of calling w3 js filter function directly, call only once the search string length is more than 2. Hope this helps..

```
    <p>
    <!--<input oninput="w3.filterHTML('#id01', '.item', this.value)" placeholder="Search for names..">-->
    <input oninput="searchFilter(this.value)" placeholder="Search for names..">
    </p>
        <script>
        function searchFilter(v) {
            var n = v.length;

            if(n>2) {
                w3.filterHTML('#id01', '.item', v);
            }
            else {
                w3.filterHTML('#id01', '.item', '');
            }
        }
    </script>
```